ARM stack padding generated by compiler
The following function,
#include <string.h>

void  func1(char *s)
{
  char buffer[4];
  strcpy(buffer, s);
}

is compiled,
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g -fno-stack-protector  func1.c -c -o func1.o
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0

and disassembled:
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump  --disassemble=func1 -S func1.o
void  func1(char *s)
{
    0:   e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
    4:   e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
    8:   e24dd010        sub     sp, sp, #16
    c:   e50b0010        str     r0, [fp, #-16]
  char buffer[4];
  strcpy(buffer, s);
    10:   e24b3008        sub     r3, fp, #8
    14:   e51b1010        ldr     r1, [fp, #-16]
    18:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
    1c:   ebfffffe        bl      0 <strcpy>
}
    20:   e1a00000        nop                     @ (mov r0, r0)
    24:   e24bd004        sub     sp, fp, #4
    28:   e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}

My analysis: just after calling strcpy() (instruction 0x20) the stack has the following contents:
         |---+---+---+---|
fp - 20  |   ?????????   | <- current $sp
         |---+---+---+---|
fp - 16  |   char * s    | <- $r1
         |---+---+---+---|
fp - 12  |   ?????????   |
         |---+---+---+---|
fp - 8   | char buffer[] | <- $r0, $r3
         |---+---+---+---|
fp - 4   |   prev $fp    | <- $sp after push
         |---+---+---+---|
         |      $lr      | <- $fp
         |---+---+---+---|
         |   |   |   |   | <- $sp that had the calling function
         |---+---+---+---|
                 .
                 .
                 .

         ^
         | descending addresses

Questions:

What is the content that $sp points to? Since ARM uses a full descending stack, that element is marked as occupied and the called function won't use that space.
Why is there unused space between the 2 local variables?


The slots prev $sp and $lr are flipped in your diagram.  The arrows point to the right entries though.

Hi @fuz thanks for commenting. I just checked in gdb and the position of pushed registers is correct. The reason is fp=r11 < lr=r14 . From documentation I can infer that the order of the arguments of push/pop doesn't matter.

Ah wait, confusingly you have drawn the stack diagram the wrong way round with the stack growing upwards (???).  This is very unconventional and has tripped me.  Sorry for that.

Note that you compiled without optimisations, effectively telling the compiler to turn off its brain.  Why do you expect optimal code, having told the compiler not to optimise the code?  It is possible that the compiler has allocated stack slots for temporaries (like the return value) that it didn't end up using.  With optimisations, these would have been removed, but you told the compiler not to do so.

The direction of the diagram is the same used by gef. I could revert it if that is more common (I'm still a novice). @fuz

Tried the -O2 option at https://godbolt.org/z/eMs4YrqG1 . It is not fully comparable because the argument is no longer stored on the stack

You can mark variables as volatile to force the compiler to put them on the stack.

Adding volatile to the argument results in the same machine code: https://godbolt.org/z/n4ahPz5de but with a warning. Maybe I should use other code to experiment.

Hm that's weird.

The answer to your first question (why the extra word at the end of the stack) is that the ARM ABI requires the stack to be 8-byte aligned at the start of every function.
Since the compiler assumes it was aligned at entry to func1, it must add an even number of words before it is allowed to call strcpy.  It knows it is wasting that extra word as padding.
I can only guess at the reason for the space between the variables.  I initially thought it was rounding the size of the array up to a multiple of 8, but this isn't correct because the padding is before the array.  Maybe it wants it to be an even offset from the frame pointer?  That isn't a very satisfying answer either.

Even with optimization enabled, things are similar: https://godbolt.org/z/WTqzxjj8K - push {lr} then sub   sp, sp, #12 , with buffer being at SP+4 so there's padding above and below, and buffer is only aligned by 4 not 8 so it's not over-aligning it.  So GCC is still reserving 8 bytes more than it needed, same as how it sometimes reserves another whole alignments worth of stack space on x86-64: Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?

Thank you. If I increase the buffer from 4 to 8 bytes the padding between locals disappears,  but not the other one.

I have managed to remove all the padding by adding another pointer argument and using a buffer of 8 bytes (like in the previous comment): https://godbolt.org/z/vj8PoPEGr

Stack is aligned to 8 on entry.  Your fp - xx is  sp - xx - 4 (which completes this answer IMHO).  The call to strcpy() should be aligned to 8.  You have just added extra elements that take care of the padding to 'get rid of it'.  Everything may or may NOT be affected by compiler options and versions, except the ABI.  This Q/A on ARM frame/link register describes -mapcs-frame or just -mapcs, depending on GCC.  Ie, always use a frame pointer.  Also, buffer[] annotation is the end of the buffer.

The other pad is between (un-needed) parameters and the local variables.  The space annotated as char * s is replace with mov r1,r0 with optimizations to setup arguments to strcpy(). With no optimization this (2nd padding) is the parameter location to func1().  Ie.  str r0, [fp, #-16] and then ldr r1, [fp, #-16],creating this stack slot and two memory transfers which -O2 replaces with a register move.  Proof, as fuz says, that the compiler dumped its brain and pretends it is on a stack machine.
